# Android widget change alarm interval

Tags: android, design-patterns, widget, alarmmanager

I have created a configure activity for my widget, where the user can choose from various update frequencies.. Until now I started the alarm in the OnEnabled() method, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60,
            pendingIntent);
```

The settings are saved in shared preferences with a unique name (widgetId) and in this OnEnabled() method I can't retrieve the settings here because I can't get the widgetId yet.
There's an another problem, the user can change the frequency anytime, but this method is called just once, at the beginning. So I think I need to start the alarm in OnUpdate(), but I don't know how to do it, I don't want to make multiple instances of an alarm accidentally so I would like to ask for some advice.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second problem, calling setRepeating multiple times will not create multiple alarm as far as you provide same PendingIntent and same request code along with PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag. I would also suggest to use setInexactRepeating instead of setRepeating. So you can use the same code in OnUpdate() too with new frequency. Go through docs of FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and setInexactRepeating for more detials.

Comment: I tried to put in OnUpdate() but I got weird result, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363798/android-widget-alarmmanager-repeating-too-fast